# Custom multitab FormEditor - resource change

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

In my Eclipse-RCP I'm using a custom implementation of the FormEditor which consists of two parts/tabs, a normal TextEditor and a custom FormPage. Saving and everything works fine, however if the tabs are switched (and the resources/file has been saved before) I don't get the changes (usually eclipse displays a message like "Resource... has been changed... Reload"). I registered a ResourceChangeListener on the workspace and I get the changes from the TextEditor (but not from the FormPage), but I still don't get a message when I switch tabs.

Thanks